# Just another thing with "Could not find the source association(s) " in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem with two tables relationship though another.

I have three models:

```
Fanfic - id | name | description | user_id
Chapter - id | name | content | fanfic_id
Vote - id | user_id | chapter_id
```

My goal is get all votes which belongs to fanfic's chapters. I tried something like this, but it doesn't working:

```
class Fanfic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :chapter
  has_many :vote, :through => :chapter
end
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Could not find the source association(s) "vote" or :vote in model Chapter. Try 'has_many :vote, :through => :chapter, :source => <name>'. Is it one of ?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow has [a number of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brails%5D+Could+not+find+the+source+association%28s%29) already that deal with this error. Have you read them and tried their solutions? Where else have you searched and why didn't those help? Read "[ask]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should fix the name of the association so it's plural:

```
has_many :chapters
has_many :votes, through: :chapters
```

Assuming, you have configured the `votes` association in your `Chapter` model:

```
has_many :votes
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you :)